# Double to float rounding problem in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, double, rounding

I have a question in kotlin. I have double and I need to cast float this. So I use toFloat() but sometimes it not work correctly.

For example;

```
1.45.toFloat() -> 1.45
11.45.toFloat() -> 11.45
111.45.toFloat() -> 111.45
```

this examples work what I want but when double values comes more than million

```
1234567.45.toFloat() -> 1234567.5
```

but I want to

```
1234567.45.toFloat -> 1234567.45
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: Float doesn't support that kind of precision. This is the reason why we have other decimal types like Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working correctly per the language.
Documentation around Float: [Kotlin Float](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float/)

Kotlin, like many languages uses IEEE-754 ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) as the standard for Floating point math and representation.

The difference of 64 bit width of a Double, and the 32 bit width of a Float means that when converting from Double to Float, we lose precision.

[image: Kotlin error for Float precision]

According to the Wiki for IEEE-754, under the table: **Basic and interchange formats** we see that the max decimal digits of a floating point, 32 bit number is 7 digits. Your example is higher than Kotlin's Float, which is a 32 bit number.

A number with one less digit will let you use the precision you need. Otherwise you will need to use a Double for numbers as large as you are expecting.

[image: incorrect float, correct float, and correct double]

As a note, Double is limited to 16 significant digits for precision

[image: double max precision]

You can use the editor suggestion for larger based numbers